# Query to calculate timespan

Tags: azure-devops

I have a pretty simple query that returns stories that are closed. We've added a few fields for start and end, so i've included those in my column options, but I'm missing is a way to get the span between those dates. I'd appreciate any help/thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Query to calculate timespan

I am afraid there is no this kind of work item query/setting will directly return the actual time takenspan for a Task from start to end.

That because Azure DevOps is not intended to be a time tracking tool. One more thing to take into account is that if a task runs over a weekend, you would not want those days to be taken into timespan if you are looking for a measure of working days on that workitem.

Your can use the workaround extracting the data to Excel, then add a list with function to analyse result, like:

[image]

Check more info from this document:

[Bulk add or modify work items with Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel?view=azure-devops-2019)

Moreover, you could also query the work item history with the TFS API and check the times tamps on when the state transitions occurred.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yea, that's what I was afraid of, I think we're just going to wind up using PowerBI to accomplish that task. I'll need to ask another question, but calculated fields in devops query?